# Further directions of index theory

Tags: noncommutative-geometry, index-theory

The Atiyah-Singer theorem is a major achievement of twentieth century mathematics. It has inspired a lot of work and people started to develop generalizations of this theorem. I would like to know the current state of the theory and current central problems in index theory. Let me mention some possible generalisations:

1. **More than one operator** This approach was initiated by Atiyah himself in the index theorem for families of operators. Possible generalizations are index theorems for foliations (for easy foliations which are *fibrations* it implies the index theorem for families).
2. **Higher index theory** This line of research concerns manifolds which are $G$-spaces and equivariant operators or more generally, noncompact (complete, Riemannian) manifolds (as in the work of John Roe). The prominent examples are universal covers of non-simply connected manifolds (where the fundamental groups acts).
3. **Non-smooth manifolds** Examples include combinatorial manifolds, Lipschitz manifolds and quasiconformal manifolds. This direction was developed mostly by Nicolae Teleman.
4. **Non-commutative geometry** This whole discipline is heavily inspired by index theory: in fact the points mentioned above use the machinery of noncommutative geometry. There is an abstract local index theorem for spectral triples of Connes-Moscovici.

> What are most important current directions and trends in index theory? What are the most important problems in index theory?

Comment: There's also index theory on certain noncompact manifolds. See in particular the Atiyah-Patodi-Singer theorem for manifolds with cylindrical ends, or Mrowka-Ruberman-Saveliev's recent [end-periodic index theorem](http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.0260). This isn't quite the same as your second bullet point, I don't think.

Answer (score 5):

Let me add some more current trends to the list.

1. *Local* and *smooth index theory.* Starting from a geometric index problem, one regards the cohomological index as a form on the underlying manifold, rather than just a cohomology class. One regards the index itself as an element of a smooth $K$-group, which includes differential form data obtained from the local index. As an example, the smooth family index of a family of Dirac operators typically involves an $\eta$-form.
2. Indices of *non-elliptic operators.* An important example is Bismut's hypoelliptic Dirac operator.